# How to override (edit) CSS colors at runtime?

Tags: css, javafx, colors

I want to make possible for users edit app UI colors via Settings menu.
Default colors are defined in .css file, for example:

```
.vertex {
   -fx-fill: rgba(64, 196, 255, 1);
}
```

In the example above I want to override -fx-fill color to whatever the user will choose from a color pickup dialog. Is it possible to update at runtime CSS class attribute ? How ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a looked-up color in the CSS file:

```css
.vertex {
    -vertex-fill: rgba(64, 196, 255, 1);
    -fx-fill: -vertex-fill ;
}
```

and then you can modify it at runtime using an inline style. You can call `setStyle()` on any ancestor of the components, and it will apply to all descendant components. E.g. to apply the change to everything in a scene with style class `.vertex`, set the style of the scene's root:

```
Color selectedColor = colorPicker.getValue();
int red = (int) (255 * selectedColor.getRed());
int green = (int) (255 * selectedColor.getGreen());
int blue = (int) (255 * selectedColor.getBlue());
double opacity = selectedColor.getOpacity();
String userColor = String.format("rgba(%d, %d, %d, %f)", red, green, blue, opacity) ;
scene.getRoot().setStyle("-vertex-fill: " + userColor + " ;");
```

Comment: How do I refer concrete CSS class ? Your example I think sets the variable in .root class. 
Also I didn't ask this explicitly in the question and I don't expect the answer  but this is important to color editing - how to convert (read) a color from .css to Color object ?

Comment: @ievgen The CSS in the external file applies the value of `-vertex-color` to the fill of anything with CSS class `vertex`. The Java code changes the value of `-vertex-color` for the `root` element, which will apply that value to all descendants of the root node. So the effect will be to change the fill of all descendants of the root node with CSS style class `vertex`. I added the code for creating a string representation of the selected color.